# Android studio hangs with no reason

Tags: android, android-studio

I have worked on a project for weeks now on android studio but few hours ago android studio just hangs with no abvious reason. I restart it, I restart the PC, I did "Invalidate Caches / Restart". I search for solutions on google but no luck specially that I don't know what's the reason.

when I open Android studio it open the project but after a few seconds it hangs even if I don't do anything at all.

Comment: why the vote down??!! can you please explain!!

Comment: I couldn't post a screenshot

Comment: I didn't downvote, but some people may have felt the question was off topic for SO or that it should be easily to google. As to your question, all I can think of that you didn't add is to try deleting and reinstalling Android Studio. If that doesn't work, open an issue in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: Thank you so much for replaying
@user4847410 you will find the idea.log in an answer because it is so long. thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

@user4847410

this is idea.log

2015-06-29 17:48:54,801 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2015-06-29 17:48:54,856 [     55]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-141.1980579, 03 Jun 2015 00:00) 
2015-06-29 17:48:54,856 [     55]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 7 (6.1, amd64) 
2015-06-29 17:48:54,856 [     55]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_45-b15 (Oracle Corporation) 
2015-06-29 17:48:54,856 [     55]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.45-b02 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2015-06-29 17:48:54,858 [     57]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.2 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Djb.vmOptions=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\boot.jar -Didea.jre.check=false 
2015-06-29 17:48:55,221 [    420]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 363 ms 
2015-06-29 17:48:55,223 [    422]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2015-06-29 17:48:55,223 [    422]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2015-06-29 17:48:56,355 [   1554]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 25 plugins initialized in 476 ms 
2015-06-29 17:48:56,358 [   1557]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.1.2.2), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage, EditorConfig (1.0), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google Cloud Testing (1.0), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Login (1.0), Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (0.1), JavaFX (1.0), Maven Integration, Properties Support, Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), hg4idea (10.0) 
2015-06-29 17:48:56,866 [   2065]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=739246080 
2015-06-29 17:48:56,904 [   2103]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\fsnotifier.exe 
2015-06-29 17:48:56,912 [   2111]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2015-06-29 17:48:57,287 [   2486]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2015-06-29 17:48:57,487 [   2686]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - We cannot bind to our default range, so, try to bind to any free port 
2015-06-29 17:48:57,781 [   2980]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 58491 
2015-06-29 17:48:57,986 [   3185]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-06-29 17:48:58,029 [   3228]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 20 project components initialized in 345 ms 
2015-06-29 17:48:58,030 [   3229]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2015-06-29 17:48:58,487 [   3686]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 83 application components initialized in 2111 ms 
2015-06-29 17:48:58,509 [   3708]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 4215 ms 
2015-06-29 17:48:59,346 [   4545]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-06-29 17:48:59,558 [   4757]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 136 project components initialized in 602 ms 
2015-06-29 17:48:59,698 [   4897]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 2 module(s) loaded in 139 ms 
2015-06-29 17:49:02,318 [   7517]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 2051 ms 
2015-06-29 17:49:03,847 [   9046]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - E:\android_studio_workspace\IraqiExc.idea\misc.xml case-sensitivity: false 
2015-06-29 17:49:04,083 [   9282]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 41 ms 
2015-06-29 17:49:04,263 [   9462]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2015-06-29 17:49:04,563 [   9762]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2015-06-29 17:49:05,113 [  10312]   INFO - nject.config.XPathSupportProxy - XPath Support is not available 
2015-06-29 17:49:05,164 [  10363]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestSupportsInput 
2015-06-29 17:49:05,164 [  10363]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens 
2015-06-29 17:49:05,411 [  10610]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 6491 ms